# mongodb and expressjs collection find all too slow

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a simple request which will return 800 entities without any where statements. Just find all. If I do a stress test to of 10,000 request per second. Each request goes beyond 30 seconds and 50% timeout. What I'm I doing wrong ? Is there a more better way to do collection.find() ?

Comment: Correction it is **10,000 request per minute** using loader.io. Roughly 100 request per second which is not much

Comment: How about caching the result into memory rather than finding it again and again

Comment: you can use .lean() after your query it will make your query fast .
e.g. `user.find({}).lean();`